# Trying to make a stored Datetime value shorter with SQL Convert function

Tags: php, mysql, datetime

I'm new to using the `convert` function. I'm trying to make a datetime value from my table shorter. Currently my datetime values look something like this, `2016-10-14 16:51:41`, but I'd like to make it look something like mm/dd/yy.

I don't know if this is the right approach (must not be since it doesn't work), but I've generated a query using the `convert` function and then fetching the data with a `mysqli_fetch_array`.

Here's the code I'm using:

```
$sql = "SELECT id, time, CONVERT(VARCHAR(11), time) as something FROM tableName";
$query = mysqli_query($db, $sql);
$statusnumrows = mysqli_num_rows($query);

// Gather data about parent pm's
if($statusnumrows > 0){
    while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($query, MYSQLI_ASSOC)) {
        $time= $row["time"];
    }
}
```

`Time` is the name of the column which has the datetime type.

Thanks in advance, for suggestions/advice.

Comment: Based on your code, I guess that you are using MySQL, so I change tags. Add PHP tag also.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should store datetime in your DB in proper data types like **datetime** [etc](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/date-and-time-types.html).

As I can see you are using PHP, if you need to OUTPUT this datetime in some interface (f.e. HTML page), you should use PHP functions to convert date in format you need. That is the good practice

DB should STORE the data but formatting is front-end problem.

Simple example of `strtotime()` and `date()`:

```
$Date = "2016-10-15";
$newDate = date("m/d/Y", strtotime($Date));
```

You can read docs on the PHP site: [strtotime](http://php.net/strtotime) and [date](http://php.net/date)

Comment: Thanks for your help! It worked perfectly! Thanks again!

Comment: My pleasure! ;)

Answer (score 1):

If 2012+ you could use format (not very efficient but does offer some other possibilities)

```
Declare @Date DateTime = GetDate()

Select UsingFormat     = Format(@Date,'MM/dd/yy')
      ,UsingConvert1   = convert(varchar(10),@Date,1)
      ,UsingConvert101 = convert(varchar(10),@Date,101)
```

Returns

```
UsingFormat UsingConvert1   UsingConvert101
10/15/16    10/15/16        10/15/2016
```

Comment: Do you have any idea why `FORMAT` is quite slow when compared to other Internal function

Comment: @Prdp  Saw an article and ran some tests myself.   I was shocked.    I suspect they tried to pack too much into the function.     https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/3018/performance-comparison-of-the-sql-server-parse-cast-convert-and-tryparse-trycast-tryconvert-functions/

Answer (score 0):

Use style `1` in `Convert` function for `mm/dd/yy` format

```
select CONVERT(VARCHAR(20), [time],1) 
From yourtable
```

If you want `mm/dd/yyyy` format then use `101` style

```
select CONVERT(VARCHAR(20), [time],101) 
From yourtable
```

MSDN link for Convert function with various style : [**CONVERT**](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-in/library/ms187928.aspx)

Comment: Thanks for your answer! Sorry if this is a silly question, but do I still need to use the mysqli_fetch_array? I'm trying to display the time value, but I'm not having any luck at the moment.

Comment: @Millica - I dont have any idea about `mysqli_fetch_array` am a database guy.

Comment: @Millica yes, you need to use `mysqli_fetch_array` in order to fetch data from your database and output it somehow. But how to use it properly is another question. I suggest you to search [PHP.net docs](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-result.fetch-array.php) for more info and examples. You need to use `$time= $row["something"];` because you call this column `something` in your query. What brings you `echo $time` after fetching?